# Unbale to find wordpress mysql docker ,succeed connect mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

i install wordpress with docker ,and mysql connected successfully,but i can't find my wordpress mysql data . i use mysql client to connet mysql server docker ,i can't find data.

```css
version: "3.9"
    
services:
  db:
    container_name: mysql-bbpress-compose  
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234567
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    
  wordpress:
    container_name: wrodpress-bbpress-compose   
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "1080:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
  db_data: {}
  wordpress_data: {}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYH27.png)
I can't fidn DB wordpress

Comment: Both containers need to be in the same network: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the database from host? If so then you should publish port in `db` container and connect to it.

Comment: @MarkoE Both containers are in a Compose-managed network named `default`.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes this further.